# Special sum equation

Tags: excel

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSoX8.jpg]

Example:

> For 68841-01, I need the column "result" to have 6.9.
>
> For 68841-02, I need the column "result" to have 0.
>
> For 68841-03, I need the column "result" to have 19.38+2.98+5+2.54=29.9 (since 68841-03 occurred 3 times).

Basically, I need to have all rows that have MasterJobNo to be added to the equivalent Jobno's row.

I need an equation, not vba.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/iSoX8.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another play on the formula:

```
=IF(B2="",SUM(SUMIF(A:A,A2,C:C),SUMIF(B:B,A2,C:C)),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In D1, enter this and drag down (adjust ranges as necessary): `=IF(B2="",C2+SUMIF($B$2:$B$13,A1,$C$2:$C$13),"")`

Edited per @AFranklin's comment.

Comment: The data starts in row 2, so change D1 to D2, and B1 to B2, etc. But other than that minor point, this should be a solid solution!

Comment: That's what I get when I am trying to make lunch instead of answering,  I get beat by a billionaire playboy.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Sorry! But I must say you've beaten me dozens of times as I sit in my hot tub drinking champagne ...er, I mean working.